# printing a collection item to immediate window in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering how do I print an item in my collection to the immediate window in excel VBA? I want to either have a collection for each collection item or an array for each collection item, which ever is easier to pull information from. Here is some example code of what I'm talking about

```
Sub test()

Dim c As Collection
Dim a As Collection

Set a = New Collection

For i = 1 To 10
    Set c = New Collection
    c.Add Array("value1", "value2", "value3","valvue4, "value5"), "key1"
    c.Add "value2", "key2"
    c.Add "value3", "key3"
    c.Add "value4, "key4"
    c.Add "value5", "key5"

    a.Add c, c.Item(1)    

'lets say I wanted to print value4 or value1 from the 1st item
Debug.Print a.Item(1(2))

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to @Gary's Student's answer, you can't use integers as keys for a collection. So you either cast them to a string using the Cstr function or you can use a dictionary instead. If you decide to use a dictionary, make sure to enable the Microsoft Scripting Runtime (under tools -> references). I've added some examples below.

```
    Sub collExample()
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim c As Collection

        Set c = New Collection
        For i = 1 To 10
            c.Add 2 * i, CStr(i)
        Next i
        'keys cant be integers
        'see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/f26wd2e5(v=vs.100).aspx

        For i = 1 To 10
            c.Item (i)
        Next i
    End Sub

    Sub dictExample()
        Dim d As New Dictionary
        Dim i As Integer

        For i = 1 To 10
            d(i) = 2 * i
        Next i

        Dim k As Variant
        For Each k In d
            Debug.Print k, d(k)
        Next k

        Dim coll As New Collection
        coll.Add "value1"
        coll.Add "value2"
        coll.Add "value3"

        Set d("list") = coll

        Dim newCol As Collection
        Set newCol = d("list")

        Dim v As Variant
        For Each v In newCol
            Debug.Print v
        Next v

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
Sub ytrewq()
    Dim c As Collection
    Set c = New Collection
    c.Add "x", CStr("x")
    c.Add "y", CStr("y")
    c.Add "z", CStr("z")
    i = 2
    MsgBox c.Item(i)
    Debug.Print c.Item(i)
End Sub
```